# Telegram Bot API - Upload document with filename

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

How is it possible to send a document in telegram in python with an other filename that "document"?
I'm using the Python3. "doc" is a clear text i want to send as txt file.

```
url = baseurl + token + '/sendDocument'
dict = {'chat_id':chat_id}
r = requests.post(url, params=dict, files={'document':doc})
```

The received file is named "document", without a file extension. When I rewrite the files to

```
files={'document.txt':doc}
```

the Telegram replies

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: there is no document in the request"}
```

Does anyone know how to set a file name for the file?

Comment: why do you need a custom name for a document?

Comment: It is about openvpn config files. They should have the ending .ovpn to be associated with the app, and doesn't have to be renamed manually by the user.

Answer (score 3):

According to the API page, you cannot do that. You must use predefined names for such types of API methods (`document`, `photo`, `audio`, etc.).

And even if you could - you won't be able to use your custom name to find your files because Telegram bot API uses its own `file_id` identifier for this purpose.

As a workaround you may store `file_id`—`your_custom_document.txt` relation on your backend and use `file_id` to communicate with Telegram servers.

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this:

```
url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{settings.TG_TOKEN}/sendDocument'
response = requests.post(url, data=data, files = {'document': ('filename.html', file.read())})
```